# Language extensions and new keywords

Tags: c++

What does a standard say about extending a C++ language and adding 'non standard' keywords? Do the keyword have to start with __ (double underscore) or can the be 'regular', meaning starting with a letter?  If I would about to create extension to C++ and have a new keyword do I have to make it look like this:

```
__new_keyword
```

or can it be just simple:

```
new_keyword.
```

Thanks.

Comment: There is no way to extend C++ at the syntax level (ie new keywords). What is it that you are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @LokiAstari: While you're technically correct, there are a couple of libraries etc with pseudo-keywords, like `signals:`, `public slots:` and `emit` in Qt. These are actually macros.

Comment: @LokiAstari have to politely disagree with you. MS just extended C++ called it C++/CX and add new keywords to it and new syntax. So it can be done.

Comment: @smallB. Microsoft writes the compiler. They can extended it anyway they want. You have no such ability to touch the compiler. But my original question stands what are you trying to achieve. C++ is very versatile we can probably tell you a way to achieve your goal within what is possible.

Comment: @LokiAstari not their compiler but mine.

Comment: @LokiAstari and by saying 'anyway they want' you mean that they can add new keywords without underscores and that will be ok with std?

Comment: Of course it can be done like MS did with C++/CLI, but then it isn't technically C++ anymore just something that resembles and works almost like C++ a lot. The big question here is why? To make a "new" language based on C++ you better have a **very** good reason.

Comment: @smallB. No. They can extended in anyway they want. But any changes make it non conforming to the standard. It is in effect a new language.

Comment: @smallB: By definition, language extensions are not part of the C++ language. So they don't _have_ to follow the rules of the C++ language. Therefore, Microsoft, or yourself, can do whatever you want in a language extension, because it's _not_ C++ anymore. However, if you want to ensure that you don't step on someone's identifiers, then you should name your extra keywords in the way that the standard has provided protection.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas that what I'm asking for. IF I'm creating extension to C++ *CAN I* use keywords starting with a letter *OR* do I have to start them with underscore? That's all I'm asking about.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg on a humorous note: MS did this extension to C++ even though there seems to be no good reason for that. Check here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/10/20/10228473.aspx

Comment: @smallB: You can't and be standard compliant. If you are not standard compliant then you can do anything you want. But you first need to get the source of a compiler. If you have to ask this question then doing this may be biting off more than you can chew.

Comment: @LokiAstari It is purely theoretical question. And yes, of course I'm too smallB yet to starting something like this. I just want to know that.

Comment: @LokiAstari and I think if someone says language extension it implicitly means that it won't be std conformant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard says that identifiers with two underscores are reserved for the compiler. So if you want a safe way to add language extensions in your C++ compiler, that would be one way to do it. Be advised that if you're just writing a pre-processor, the compiler you use may conflict with what you choose. But since the pre-processed code should be fairly simple, it shouldn't be a problem.

> IF I'm creating extension to C++ CAN I use keywords starting with a letter OR do I have to start them with underscore?

You *CAN* do whatever you want, because it won't be C++ and therefore does not have to conform to anything. However, if you want to keep conflicts with user-created names to a minimum, the standard says that identifiers that begin with two underscores are reserved by the C++ implementation, as are identifiers that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter.

Note that this will only stop you from conflicting with user code. You can still conflict with your standard library implementation or whatever compiler you're working with.

Comment: Any reason for the -1? Am I wrong on the double-underscore thing?

Comment: thanks, that's what I was asking for. By the way, this -1 wasn't from me.